# Bacondecomp how to handle with missing values

Tags: r, diff, fixed, decomposition, two-way

I'm trying to do a difference-in-difference regression with multiple time periods and I am trying to decompose the coefficient using bacon decomposition. In my dep var there are some missing values. When I run the bacon decomp I have this error. Any suggestion on how to handle it? I have reported the error code.
Error in bacon(crime ~ post, data = panel, id_var = "fips", :
NA observations

Thanks for your help

Comment: Have you tried changing `data = panel` to  `data = panel[complete.cases(panel))]` ?

Comment: Error: Must subset columns with a valid subscript vector.
i Logical subscripts must match the size of the indexed input.
x Input has size 69 but subscript `complete.cases(rtc_data_panel)` has size 1924.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: bacon = bacon(ln_Homicide_rate ~post,data = data_panel,id_var = "fips",time_var = "year"). ln_homicide rate has missing value so I have this error:Error in bacon(ln_Homicide_rate ~ post, data = data_panel, id_var = "fips",  : 
  NA observations. I have tried complete.case as suggested but I have gotten the error reported above. Any suggestion?